# how to save information from a file in java

Tags: java, string, file, io

I am supoose to read a file lets say it has 3 lines:

```
2

Berlin 0 2 2 10000 300

Nilreb 0 2 2 10000 300
```

the first integer number shows how many names(lines) i have.

the 2nd and 3rd lines show information about two post offices.

them i am suppose to read each line and save the data.

I have to create post offices that they are names: Berlin and Nilreb.

Can anyone help me?

so far i have done this:

```
public static void read_files() throws IOException{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("offices")); //open and read the file
    int num_of_lines = in.nextInt();
    while(in.hasNext()){
        String offices = in.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: `Scanner` also has `nextInt` and similar other functions which would be useful to you.

Comment: Are you going to create a PostOfficer class to store data?

Comment: yes im creating PostOffice class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read files I recommend to you to use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(//Here the path of your file));

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

while (s.hasNext())
{
    list.add(s.nextLine());
}
```

Now in your `ArrayList` you will have all the lines of your file. So, now, you can go through all the post offices that you have with a for loop (I start in the index 1 because the first line it's the line of how many post offices are in the file, you won't need it with this method) and `split` them to get all the information about them. For example, in the position 0 of the array of `Strings` you will have the name of your post Office and in the rest of the positions (1,2,3,4...) the rest of your values stored in your file (one value by space in your line). Like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
{
   String[] line  = list.get(i).split(" ");

   System.out.println("The name of this post office is " + line[0]);
}
```

**EDIT:** I saw now in a comment above that you want to create a class for each line. Then you can do (inside the for loop, instead of the `System.out.println`) the code that I put below (supossing that your class will be `PostOffice`):

```
PostOffice postOffice = new PostOffice(line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],line[5]);
```

Note: If you don't understand something about my code please let me know.

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out: can u check if it is correct:

```
public static void read_files() throws IOException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("offices"));
        int num_of_lines = in.nextInt();
        String[] office = new String[num_of_lines];
        while(in.hasNext()){
            for(int = 0; i < num_of_lines; i++){
                office[i] = in.next();
                }
```

1. ### **List item**